# adb input tap is slow

Tags: python, android, automation, adb

This is my first time trying to automate an android game and using adb.  I would like to send tap commands to my phone, but it seems like they are [too slow](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/issues/231).  I've seen that some solutions to this are to send either raw bytes, or to use get/sendevents, but I'm having trouble implementing them.  Here is the relevant code:

```
    if detect_tile(c1):
       device.shell("input touchscreen tap 90 943")
```

What would you suggest for implementation?

*note: my device is not rooted*

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69751137/how-to-make-adb-tap-fast-adbpython

Answer (score 0):

it's happened to me before. When I click PIN number (6 numbers) at a bank application by using adb input tap it takes time around **3 - 4 seconds** but when I use [monkeyrunner](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkeyrunner), it's able to automate taps very fast and takes time around **0.5 - 1 second**.

You can try to use the monkeyrunner tool. It uses [Jython](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jython/index.htm), but the syntax is almost the same as Python.