# How to make adb tap fast (ADB+Python)

Tags: android, python-3.x, bots, adb, androidviewclient

So I made a bot for a singleplayer android game, using python and adb.
The biggest problem is that between each tap there is like a 1 second delay.

I connect to the device like this -

```
from ppadb.client import Client

def Get_device_adb():
    adb = Client(host="127.0.0.1", port=5037)

    devices = adb.devices()
    if len(devices) == 0:
        print("No device attached")
        quit()

    return devices[0]

device = Get_device_adb()
```

and use shell input tap to send my taps -

```
taps = [(225, 750), (350, 800), ...]
for tap in taps:
    device.shell(f"input tap {tap[0]} {tap[1]}")
```

For the game I need the taps to happen as fast as possible one after another, and currently they have a 1 second delay between them.

By the way, I really want this script to run in python and not in jython

So is there a way to make adb tap faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [AndroidViewClient/cuelbra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) using [CluebraTester2-public](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public) backend and you can get a much higher rate.

Here is an example script

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time
from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()

kwargs2 = {'useuiautomatorhelper': True}
vc = ViewClient(device, serialno, **kwargs2)

taps = [(225, 750), (350, 800), (100, 100), (300, 300), (150, 150), (100, 200)]
for tap in taps:
    print(f'{time.time()}: touching @{tap}')
    vc.touch(tap[0], tap[1])
```

using an emulator I could obtain

```
1635459899.020685: touching @(225, 750)
1635459899.202344: touching @(350, 800)
1635459899.522454: touching @(100, 100)
1635459899.703721: touching @(300, 300)
1635459899.8933198: touching @(150, 150)
1635459903.257416: touching @(100, 200)
```

which gives approx. 1 touch every 200 ms.

#### edit

There's a new answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/72268342/236465 that reduces the time per click to around 100ms

Comment: Thanks, I pip installed the ViewClient but I am having a hard time installing the CulebraTester2 back end server, I already installed the app.zip and instrumentation.zip on my computer but I dont understand what to do next, can you help me please?
(and my phone is also connected with adb by usb)

Comment: You donwloaded and installed the 2 apks (app & instrumentation) on your device. Then you can run `bash <(curl -sL https://git.io/JT5nc) start-server` to start the server. Once the server is running you can execute the above script. Feel free to follow up with another question (use tag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/androidviewclient).

Comment: Thank you, but I am using windows is there a way to do it in windows 10?

Comment: Yes, `gitbash` should work. Otherwise, you can just reproduce the simple command s to `forward_port && run_instrumentation` that are inside https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public/blob/master/culebratester2 script.

Comment: So on the gitbash I wrote -
adb install app-debug.apk.
adb install app-debug-and-roidTest.apk.
bash <(curl -sL https://git.io/JT5nc) start-server.

Im getting this error -
"app and instrumentation apks should be installed".
I also tried to rename app-debug.apk -> app.apk and app-debug-and-roidTest.apk -> instrumentation.apk. But I still get the sam error

Comment: Once you have installed and APK (the local name doesn't matter) and having the device connected via ADB, what's the output of `adb shell pm list packages | grep -c com.dtmilano.android.culebratester2` ? That's how the script is checking they are both installed.

Comment: The output is 1, I also scrolled down after writing "adb shell pm list packges" and I can see package:com.dtmilano.android.culebratester2 is in the list.

Comment: "bash <(curl -sL https://git.io/JT5nc) start-server" still returns "ERROR: app and instrumentation apks should be installed."

Comment: But the output should be **2**, as two APKs should be installed (app & instrumentation). You are missing 1. Check the status when you install them to verify there is no error.

Comment: A new version of `culabratester2` script has been uploaded. Try run it again. The output should be more helpful.

Comment: I reinstalled the apks, now it says 2 in the adb list, and with the new culabratester2 script it runs without errors! The python script taps are as fast as I need them, Thank you very much :D

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Comment: Hi using vc.touch is fine with your method. However, using vc.swipe() give me error: RuntimeError: this method should not be used