# Is there a faster way to emulate tap in android using Python in PC?

Tags: python, android, adb

I tried:

```
from ppadb.client import Client
adb = Client()
device = adb.devices[0]

device.shell('input tap x y')
```

but it just takes too long. Is there a faster alternative to it?

Comment: How slow is too slow? One hundred clicks takes 6.9 seconds for me.

Comment: Not sure if ppadb supports this but you would save a lot of time if you could reuse the shell. Establishing the shell is most likely one of the most time consuming steps. in your code.

Comment: @importrandom just one click takes 1-2 seconds. is it because my pc's specs are low, or is just the shell slow?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69751137/how-to-make-adb-tap-fast-adbpython this solution rate is about 200ms per touch.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code to clarify my simple timing test:

```
import time
from ppadb.client import Client

client = Client()
devices = client.devices()
device = devices[0]

start = time.time()
for _ in range(100):
    # device.input_tap(200, 200)
    device.shell('input tap 200 200')
print(f"Finished in {time.time() - start:.1f} seconds")
```

On my system (Win10, Python3.9) this prints values between 6.6 and 7.2 seconds. Using `input_tap(x,y)` instead of `shell('input tap x y')` doesn't change the timing.

Answer (score 0):

This is an improvement over [How to make adb tap fast (ADB+Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69751137/how-to-make-adb-tap-fast-adbpython) answer.

In that answer, the method suggested achieves a rate of about 200ms per click.

This new solution, using again [CulebraTester2-public](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public), but this time using  [CulebraTester2-client](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-client) directly instead of through [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) (*not because I think it may introduce any overhead but just to show another alternative*).

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import culebratester_client
import random
import time

N = 100
CONFIGURATION = None
# areas we don't want to click on for the Keep notes app
Y_OFFSET = 200
Y_BOTTOM = 100

def rp(w, h):
    x = random.randint(0, w)
    y = random.randint(Y_OFFSET, h - Y_BOTTOM)
    return culebratester_client.models.point.Point(x, y)


api_instance = culebratester_client.DefaultApi(culebratester_client.ApiClient(CONFIGURATION))

w = api_instance.ui_device_display_width_get().display_width
h = api_instance.ui_device_display_height_get().display_height

points = [rp(w, h) for n in range(N)]
body = culebratester_client.models.click_body.ClickBody(points)
start = time.time()
api_response = api_instance.ui_device_click_post(body=body)
end = time.time()
elapsed = end - start
print(f'{api_response}')
print(f'{N} clicks in {elapsed:.4f} secs ({(elapsed/N)*1000:.2f} ms per click)')
```

The results are less than half of previous solution:

```
{'error_message': None, 'status': 'OK', 'status_code': None}
100 clicks in 9.5429 secs (95.43 ms per click)
```

and if you run it while you have Google Keep open, you can see the clicks

[image: keep note]