# How to perform multi touch using Culebratester-Client?

Tags: python, android, adb, androidviewclient

I've succeeded to perform a quick tap using [Culebra-Client](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-client) by following code from this stackoverflow  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72268342/236465). But I still don't understand how to perform multiple touch

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you describe your use case? How many pointers do you need? The difference is that [UiDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/uiautomator/UiDevice) does not support multitouch. However, it might be implemented in [CulebraTester-public](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public) using [UiObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/uiautomator/UiObject), currently it's not implemented.

Comment: Check https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-client/blob/master/docs/DefaultApi.md#ui_object_oid_perform_two_pointer_gesture_post which adds 2-pointer multitouch gestures

Answer (score 0):

A quick example using the newly introduced API in [2.0.47](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public/actions/runs/3180184888) to handle multi touch. It uses [MultiTouch Tester](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.the511plus.MultiTouchTester&hl=en_US&gl=US) to show the touches but you can use any app.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from culebratester_client import PerformTwoPointerGestureBody, Point
from pprint import pprint
from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient, KEY_EVENT

helper = ViewClient(*ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(), useuiautomatorhelper=True).uiAutomatorHelper

# multitouch tester
id = 'com.the511plus.MultiTouchTester:id/touchStr'
oid = helper.ui_device.find_object(ui_selector=f'res@{id}').oid

api_instance = helper.api_instance
try:
    body = PerformTwoPointerGestureBody(start_point1=Point(300, 100), start_point2=Point(900, 100), end_point1=Point(300, 1600), end_point2=Point(900, 1600), steps=500)
    api_response = api_instance.ui_object_oid_perform_two_pointer_gesture_post(oid, body=body)
    pprint(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception when calling DefaultApi->ui_object_oid_perform_two_pointer_gesture_post: %s\n" % e)
```

Once you run it, the 2 pointers will be recognized by the app.

[image]

Comment: For a more polished example check: https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/examples/helper/multitouch