# How to efficiently control multiple android devices in parallel with python?

Tags: python, android, multithreading, adb, selenium-grid

I am a computer science student in Belgium working on a project that involves **simultaneously controlling multiple Android devices from a Python script**. During testing, I’m encountering challenges in implementing effective multithreading with Android Studio emulators, which I’m utilizing initially before connecting to real devices. I’ve explored solutions like Appium and Selenium server, but finding clear information and straightforward workflows matching my needs is proving difficult.

I attempted using ADB and Appium, but could only control one phone at a time. My experiments with Appium and Selenium server have been challenging, and I’m struggling to find clear information or simple workflows for this task.

This situation stop my progress, and I welcome any suggestions or advice that could simplify the process of simultaneously controlling Android emulators via Python. Each emulator should not perform the same tasks; they should follow a procedural path outlined by the Python script. I’m open to change completely the workflow that I tried to implement.

Below is my attempt to retrieve connected devices using ADB and an initial try to launch Appium servers for each device:

```
# Function to get connected devices
def get_connected_devices():

    devices_configs = []
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output([adb_path, 'devices']).decode('utf-8')
        devices = output.strip().split('\n')[1:]


        for device in devices:
            ud_id = device.split('\t')[0]
            os_version = (
                subprocess.check_output(
                    [
                        adb_path,
                        '-s',
                        ud_id,
                        'shell',
                        'getprop',
                        'ro.build.version.release',
                    ]
                )
                .decode('utf-8')
                .strip()
            )
            platform = "Android"
            system_port = str(8200 + len(devices_configs))
            chrome_driver_port = str(8100 + len(devices_configs))
            device_details = {
                "device": ud_id,
                "os_version": os_version,
                "ud_id": ud_id,
                "platform": platform,
                "systemPort": system_port,
            }
            devices_configs.append(device_details)
        return devices_configs
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error executing ADB command: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")

# Retrieve connected devices
connected_devices = get_connected_devices()

# Start Appium servers for each device
processes = []
for i in range(len(connected_devices)):
    port = 4724 + i
    cmd = ["start", "appium", "-p", str(port)]
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
    processes.append(process)
```

Despite this, I encountered issues with forcing Appium to use specific device ports, as it kept using the same port for all devices:

```
# Pair each connected device with a server
device_server_pairs = list(zip(connected_devices, servers))

# Start Appium sessions using threads
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(start_appium_session, device_server_pairs)

# Function to start Appium session for each device
def start_appium_session(device_config_server_tuple):
    device_config, server = device_config_server_tuple
    capabilities = {
        'platformName': device_config['platform'],
        'platformVersion': device_config['os_version'],
        'deviceName': device_config['ud_id'],
        'systemPort': device_config['systemPort'],
        'app': APP_PATH,
    }

    driver = webdriver.Remote(server, options=UiAutomator2Options().load_capabilities(capabilities))
```

I appreciate any insights or improvements you could provide.

Comment: Control devices to do what?

Comment: Hi @zomega , it need to perform actions like writing or sending pictures, and ideally, to establish real-time data communication with Python (like get text from a specific spot and then writing something else back to the device)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) which can connect to multiple devices at a time.

You can find some videos at https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Resources#screencasts-and-videos, particularly **Culebra GUI: Multi-device tests**. While it shows the same test script being run on all the devices there's nothing that prevents you from running completely different things.

Comment: Hey, appreciate a lot your input, thanks! I’ve explored AndroidViewClient/culebra, but it seems a bit slow based on the videos I’ve watched. Can you confirm its capabilities for retrieving and sending text from the device? I’m considering a deeper dive, but the array of possibilities is a bit overwhelming.

I’m also curious about https://epd-blog.entri.team/unlocking-the-power-of-parallel-mobile-automation-with-python-appium-and-raspberry-pi-b264467c50fc or https://maestro.mobile.dev. They seem promising, but I’m not sure. Any thoughts or recommendations on these approaches?

Comment: There are many factors involved to measure performance. Most of the videos show *code generation* which it might be slow as, depending on the conditions, the whole view tree needs to be analyzed. That's different than running the generated script or creating scripts manually. On the contrary, AVC/culebra is perhaps the fastest way of doing what you want (i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69761688/236465). But you should compare the different tools for your specific use case.

Comment: https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/examples/helper/battery-status-multi-device might be another good example